# Refresh stored webclients configurations in Map of Fluxes

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a big struggle on my side and maybe someone, somehow know the answer or at least a lead to hang into :D To the point - I have an environment on spring boot where i store Fluxes of defined webclients (that connects to different hosts ) in a map at the to connect to and get data. If someone from the front-end side asks for the same source of data, i return data from the cache instead of creating a new webclient instance :)

It woks like a charm, but everything collapses when ip/port is changed on the instance - then users cannot get data from the stored webclient because it point's to a invalid connection :( . I've thought about several solutions to the problem:

- Detect no active subscribers and delete it from the map
- Schedule a cleanup action to remove old unused / failed fluxes
- Define action in back propagation mechanism to swap connection
  details

In code below I have put a definition of cache manager.

I would be very grateful for any kind of help or advice how to handle this hard cookie :D

````
public abstract class CachedFluxReactiveManager<T, M extends FiltreableCommand> extends CachedReactiveManager<T, M, Flux<T>> {
protected final Map<ReactiveCallsKey, Flux<T>> connections = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
protected final FluxClientCreator<T> clientCreator;
protected final InstancesQueryCreator queryCreator;
private final boolean useCache;

protected CachedFluxReactiveManager(InstancesCache instancesCache, FluxClientCreator<T> clientCreator,
        InstancesQueryCreator queryCreator, boolean useCache) {
    super(instancesCache);
    this.clientCreator = clientCreator;
    this.queryCreator = queryCreator;
    this.useCache = useCache;
}

@Override
public Flux<T> getData(M command) {

    if (useCache) {
        if (command.isFiltered()) {
            return createAndReturnConnection(command).next().flux();
        }

        return ofNullable(getConnectionIfExists(command))
                .orElseGet(() -> createAndReturnConnection(command));
    } else {
        return createAndReturnConnection(command);
    }
}

@Override
protected Flux<T> getConnectionIfExists(M command) {
    return connections.get(
            getReactiveCallsKey(command.getApplicationName(), command.getTicker(), command.getReferenceEx()));
}}```
````

Comment: did you consider using cache library like Caffeine?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there require some similar operation to health check.

```java
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
            .tcpConfiguration(client ->
                client.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 3000)
                    .doOnDisconnected(conn -> {
                        //todo Remove the cached connection.
                    }));
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
     .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
     .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

At first - thanks @echooymxq and @Martin Tarjányi
for the answers - in a way both helped me to pimp my code. Here is what I did:

- **I've changed the implementation of the cache to Caffeine which simplified a lot for me :D**

```
    // the cache implementation
        protected Cache<ReactiveCallsKey, Flux<T>> connections;
        
    // cache configuration (cleanup) 
            protected final Cache<ReactiveCallsKey, Flux<T>> connections = Caffeine.newBuilder()
                    .maximumSize(10_000)
                    .expireAfterAccess(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                    .build();
```

- **found a problem, that i did not cleaned up the cache while something went awful**

```
    protected Flux<T> manageConnectionConfiguration(ReactiveCall reactiveCall,
                    Flux<T> out) {
                return out.doOnError(throwable -> {
                            removeInstanceCallFromCache(reactiveCall);
                            log.error("connection error for {} reactive source",
                                    reactiveCall.getApplicationName(),
                                    new OperationException(systemExceptionMessage, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                                            throwable));
                        })
                        .doOnSubscribe(
                                subscription -> log.debug("subscription established for {} ", reactiveCall.getApplicationName()))
                        .doOnComplete(() -> log.debug("subscription completed for {} ", reactiveCall.getApplicationName()));
            }
protected void removeInstanceCallFromCache(ReactiveCall reactiveCall) {
                Try.run(() -> connections.invalidate(
                        new ReactiveCallsKey(reactiveCall.getApplicationName(), reactiveCall.getTicker(),
                                reactiveCall.getReference())));
            }
```

- **also I've adjusted the waiting time for timeouts**  but in the end i've reverted this change as default's were fine :)